# Prestashop 1.6 get instance of module class

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have an overridden class `OrderConfirmationControllerCore`.

I have a modul with class `Abra`.

I need to get an instance of `Abra` class in the `OrderConfirmationControllerCore`

My code is:

```
class OrderConfirmationController extends OrderConfirmationControllerCore
{
    public function init()
    {      
       $abraSetDocs = new Abra();
       parent::init();
    }
}
```

This generates error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Abra' not found in /../override/controllers/front/OrderConfirmationController.php on line 39
```

How can I get the instance of the class?

Comment: Is `Abra extends ObjectModel` or `Abra extends Module` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$abraSetDocs = Module::getInstanceByName('abra');
```

Note that 'abra' is the name of the module ($this->name from the module __construct()), not the class name.

Comment: How to properly require `Module` class from an arbitrary file within another module?

Comment: I am helping to debug one module, I cannot access `Module` class, I tested with `class_exists('Module')` which is always `false` in my case.

Comment: if you are willing to help I opened a new question for that purpose http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303955/prestashop-cannot-require-module-class

Comment: I [just learned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54470465/875020) that you dont need to hardcode the modules name but can instead access it via `$this->module->name` and also dont need to call `Module::getInstanceByName()` but instead access `$this->module`.

Comment: @x29a The guy needs an instance of a specific module. An example in the link is within the context of ModuleFrontController, while this is whithin OrderConfirmationController which does not even have module property. Completely different case.

Comment: @PrestaShopDeveloper ok thank you for your clarification.