# Prestashop, cannot require Module class

Tags: php, module, prestashop, autoload

#### Problem

Related [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585399/prestashop-1-6-get-instance-of-module-class), I have been trying to apply related solution to my project, however I am not able to execute

```
Module::getInstanceByName('modulename');
```

I do not even have access to `Module` class, which makes it hard for me to access application context and my own module context

```
class_exists('Module')
```

Returns `false`.

I also provide the directory structure of my module from which I am attempting to access `Module`.

```
├── mymodule.php
├── config.xml
└── somedirectory
    └── index.php
```

Where `mymodule.php` follows the module class [guidelines](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+first+module#Creatingafirstmodule-Themainclass) and `index.php` is just php file in which I attempt to access other modules. most important for me is to access the context of my own module so that I can retrieve for example it's version and other settings.

#### Example source

Example of `index.php` from my `testmodule`, this example is for `1.4` but I am also willing to have it working for `1.5` and `1.6`

```
require('../../../config/settings.inc.php');
require('../../../classes/Module.php');
$instance = Module::getInstanceByName('mymodule');
```

This crashes, and when I use

```
require('../../../config/settings.inc.php');
require('../../../classes/Module.php');
if (class_exists('Module')) {
    echo "class exists";
} else {
    echo "class does not exists";
}
```

It outputs `class does not exists`.

The reason I require `../../../config/settings.inc.php` is to demonstrate that there are some classes I can require and it works. I am able to access constants defined inside of `settings.inc.php`

So the file at relative path `../../../classes/Module.php` exists and it contains

```
...
public static function getInstanceByName($moduleName)
...
```

#### Questions

1. How to properly access `Module` class to access instance of particular module just as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585399/prestashop-1-6-get-instance-of-module-class). What is the proper way of loading Prestashop classes from within an arbitrary file in the custom module.
2. Why I can import `../../../config/settings.inc.php` using `require` and it doesn't apply to `../../../classes/Module.php`?
3. This issue concerns Prestashop `1.4`, however I would like to know if can this be applied also for `1.5` and `1.6`, I noticed that for those versions `classes/module.php` does not exists instead there is `classes/module/Module.php`. General solution would be the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call your `index.php` file directly (`http://www.example.com/modules/mymodule/somedirectory/index.php`) you're not using Prestashop internal Dispatcher. This means that Prestashop is not loaded when your `index.php` script is executed.

If you want to load Prestashop your first need to include `/config/config.inc.php`:

```php
require('../../../config/config.inc.php');
if (class_exists('Module')) {
    echo "class exists";
} else {
    echo "class does not exists";
}
```

If you want to use Prestashop standard Dispatcher process, you will have to create a [ModuleFrontController](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Controllers+within+PrestaShop).

Comment: Just tested. Solves my problem and explains the reason why it didn't work. Perfect answer. Thank you.